# Elixir: How to persist OTP queue if server restarts?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, erlang-otp

I am using OTP for managing a queue of events:

```
defmodule ParrotApi.MatchingSupervisor do
  use Supervisor

  ## Callbacks

  def start_link() do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  end

  def init(_) do
    children = [
      worker(ParrotApi.MatchingServer, []), # TODO: State is gone if this crashes

      # Supervise connections
      supervisor(Registry, [:unique, :connection_registry]),
      supervisor(ParrotApi.ConnectionSupervisor, []),
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

My question is, if the server restarts, what happens to my queue? I need it to persist after restarting. To my knowledge it is stored in memory so it is wiped if the server restarts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create a separate Agent to track the state in the GenServer. The Agent is very simple, with an API to update the state, and fetch it upon request.

I create `reply(state, result)` and `noreply(state)` functions in the GenServer and call them at the end of the `handle_call`, `handle_cast`, and `handle_info` functions.

The `reply` and `no_reply` functions put the `state` in the Agent and then return the `{:no_reply, state}` and `{:reply, result, state}` tuples. I also update the agent on terminate.

When the server restarts, I check to see if its a restart and if so, pull the state from the agent in the genservers `init` callback. I just check the agent. If it does not have data, I know is a the original startup.

The idea here is that the Agent is a very simple value store. Its very simple and unlikely to fail.

You should be careful with this approach though. The idea behind the restart strategy is that the GenServer is restarted with its initial state. If your GenServer restarted because of an issue with its state, it may get into a continuous restart state.

Comment: hm so the Agent stores data on disk and is therefore recovered / persisted on a restart?

Comment: No. I was only addressing the issue of your GenServer restarting. If you need to handle an application start, you can use a database or erlang's `DETS` module. In this case, you probably don't need the Agent, you can replace the call to the Agent.put in my example above with a call to persist the data on disk. Alternatively, if you have a multi-node design I suppose you would use another node to cache the data.

Comment: I've decided to use a combination of storing the records in the db in combination with a synchronous Supervisor. That way my queue can be restored if the server goes down, and I can still guarantee that my records are processed in order

Comment: @Edmund sounds like a good approach for your requirements. BTW, I use the approach I gave above is for state that does not need to survive a server reset. Most of my solutions talk to external server through tcp sockets. If my app restarts, all the tcp links are taken down and the state gets rebuild as the tcp connections are reestablished. Also my state changes can be many thousands per second, so I can't afford database hits that often.

Comment: Makes sense. My use case is to match two users who are online (like chat roulette). So I just need to queue them up in order and dequeue the first two to "match" them.

Comment: Just out of interest why are you worried about server restarts? I have server s that run for 6, 12, or more months without restarting.

Comment: We're thinking of just using the cheapest tier of Heroku for v1, which restarts every 24 hours I believe. Out of curiosity where are you hosting your servers? AWS?

Comment: oh, that makes sense. I'm on Digital Ocean. I'm hosting three low traffic sites on a single 5$/month droplet. I'm using nginx to handle the subdomain virtual hosts. I just added letsencrypt tonight to set one up on ssl.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that it is wiped if the server restarts if by server you mean the entire machine and not just the genserver. I'd suggest storing the queue in a persistent store like a database or redis.